# How to use mule runtime for java spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, mule, mule-esb, mulesoft

Can we run our spring boot application in mule runtime inside docker container?

I am familiar with spring boot and docker and know how the deployment is done, but i am not able to figure out why we need mule runtime and how can we use our spring boot application with mule runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You would need Mule Runtime if you are trying to develop or execute Mule applications for integrations or implementing REST APIs, or similar uses. Also you could benefit from Anypoint Platform features, like API Manager.

Mule Runtime only executes Mule applications, so you would need to somehow package the Spring Boot application inside a Mule application. You should have a very clear reason to do this, otherwise the added complexity is probably not worth it.

You can deploy a Mule Runtime inside a docker container, independently from Spring Boot.